# How to show Next button in Android keyboard in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I need to show Next button in Keyboard in React Native application when there are multiple TextInput fields are there.
Could anyone suggest, I have tried with returnKeyType = {"next"} ,  blurOnSubmit and onSubmitEditing props but no use.

Could anyone you please provided the solution for this?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `returnKeyType` is the right way to do this, on Android you can use `returnKeyLabel`, as mentioned (here)[https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput#returnkeytype] If it is now showing the next button even you are using the right prop, you need to share your code sample, so that I can see for the issue.

Answer (score 4):

Try the same without {}. `returnKeyType = "next"`. This worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

You can try `onSubmitEditing` as described in the docs. This method will be called when you click done on the keyboard. In the listner, use `focus` method to focus the required textInput.

```js
render(){
  return(
    
    ...
    
    <TextInput
      ref={(input) => this._username = input}
      onSubmitEditing={() => this._email.focus()}
      value={this.state.text}
      blurOnSubmit={false}   // prevent keyboard flickering
    />
    
    <TextInput
      ref={(input) => this._email = input}
      onSubmitEditing={() => this._password.focus()} // or submit the form or focus next input and goes on
      value={this.state.text}
      blurOnSubmit={false}
    />   
    
    
  )
}
```